# PHP Sendgrid - Sender name is not being sent in mail

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am working on PHP Sendgrid.. Everything is working fine.. but the problem is

I cannot add the `Sender Name` with `from email` somehow. I think it didn't captures the `headers` or what i have no idea.

P.S : I have executed this code on a separate server and it works. But when I try to send mail from the other server with same code it sends the email but doesn't set/show the Sender Name. Is it some server side issue I am using Laravel 4? please guide

```
$headers = "From: Coffe Email" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

sendMail("myemail","mysubject","msg", $headers,$from="admin@email.com", "admin");
```

**Function's Definition (sendMail) :**

```
function sendMail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $from = "", $from_name="", $to_name="")
     { 
    require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");
            $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
            $email->setFrom($from, $from_name);
            $email->setSubject($subject);
            $email->addTo($to, $to_name);
            $email->addContent("text/plain", strip_tags($message));
            $email->addContent("text/html", $message);
            $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($settings->send_grid_user);
            try {
                $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
                print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
                print_r($response->headers());
                print $response->body() . "\n";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
            }

    }
```

Comment: this code is being executed on its own or within another application like wordpress lets say

Comment: in Laravel, version 4

Comment: yes i got the from address in email...

Comment: my mistake.. I have updated the code.. it was not complete before

Comment: you have to pass the values not the names so not $from="admin@email.com" just email@admin.com when calling the function

Comment: yeah ! but my problem is only for the headers.. they are not posting `senderName` .. everything else is just fine.

Comment: so to make sure I have this correct, you are trying to set the headers from parameter and not the sendgrid emails from parameter? Your question is not clear

Comment: @OrlandoP. Putting an assignment in a function call doesn't change the parameter being passed.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the tip, I never knew that.